# Python - Changing the accent characters in a JSON file to a regular character

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8

I currently have a JSON file that I am trying to load in python, however because of accent characters I am getting errors.

Is there a way for me to replace the accent characters to regular characters before doing the load?

I tried all methods with encoding to UTF-8 based on other post suggestions. 
Eg:

```
json.loads(line.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
```

or

```
with open("test.json", encoding='utf-8') as data_file:                           
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Since none of these options worked, I wanted to see if there is a method to replace the accent character.

Sample code:

```
import csv
import json

infile = open("infile.json","r") 
outfile = open("outfile.csv", "w") 

writer = csv.writer(outfile)
readin = json.loads(infile.read())
count = 1

for row in readin["entry1"]["entry2"]:

    if count == 1:
        writer.writerow(row.keys())
        count = count + 1

    writer.writerow(row.values())

outfile.close()
```

The above works, ONLY if there are absolutely no accent characters.

sample JSON file:

```
{
  "entry1": {
    "entry2": [
      {
        "firstName": "Sam",
        "lastName": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Jose",
        "lastName": "Peña"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like my output file to look like this:

```
firstName, lastName
Sam,XXXX
Jose,Peña
```

As you can see there is an accented ñ that I keep getting an error with.  Below is a sample error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mac/Desktop/fileconversion.py", line 8, in <module>
    readin = json.loads(infile.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1868: ordinal not in range(128)**
```

Appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Show the input, code, desired output, and actual output including error messages.  See the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Special characters require proper encoding and escaping in JSON. You might not have a valid JSON file.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Have added some sample code, sorry about that!

Comment: Also add input, desired output and actual output including error messages :^)  The goal is to enable us to reproduce your issue.  Code with no input to reproduce the error isn't enough.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Added in the sample input/output and error message. Sorry for missing that! Appreciate it.

Comment: @KlausD. No the file does seem to be valid. Is there any way I can make it valid?

Comment: Need some votes to reopen.  It has all the information now.  You need `encoding='utf8'` on both your `open` statements.  The error message suggests the encoding to me.  You can just use `json.load(infile)` as well.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you very much Mark. It works on my computer currently which runs Python 3. However, open function in Python 2, which is the version on my other laptop does not recognize this argument. I am not able to update to python 3. Do you have any suggestions for how I could do this in Python 2, specifically 2.7?

Comment: Your error message said Python 3.6.  `json.load` in Python 2.7 assumes `utf8` and also accepts an `encoding` parameter.  The Python 2 `csv` module doesn't support encodings, but the 3rd party `unicodecsv` module does.  There's also a workaround at the bottom of the `csv` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Json Input

```
import json
json_data = {"a":"\xc3\x96accentchar", "b":"normal"}
z = json.dumps(json_data)
final_data = json.loads(z)
```

Try this simple code

Comment: Your example looks like mojibake for "Ö" (UTF-8 bytes decoded with Latin-1).

Comment: Will this work for a file? Because currently, I am trying to open a JSON file and load it in python, so I can convert it to a CSV file. Will update if it works.